# Does Entity Framework 7 work on Linux Dot Net Core CLR?

Tags: linux, entity-framework, dnx

I am having a huge trouble trying to get even a simple project to run on Linux. I created a simple MVC app on windows with no fuss, however I could not migrate it to Linux. At first I thought it was platform based but now I don't think so.

I started with CentOS, following the instructions at
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html#installing-on-centos-7

I could get dnvm to run and dnx, but dotnet would just run and exit. DNX sort of worked, but when trying to access the web application it would stall, log nothing, and not exit until forced with a kill -9

Next, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and ran the commands

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet
```

Then I tried dotnet restore and got this

```
Errors in /home/joel/Projects/MVCPrototype/project.json
    Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 supports:
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile78)
    Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 supports:
      - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
    Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 supports:
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
    Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 supports:
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
    One or more packages are incompatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

NuGet Config files used:
    /home/joel/Projects/MVCPrototype/nuget.config
    /home/joel/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
    https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

So I ran these commands to uninstall the APT version and get the latest SDK

```
sudo apt-get remove dotnet
wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/beta/Installers/Latest/dotnet-host-ubuntu-x64.latest.deb
wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/beta/Installers/Latest/dotnet-sharedframework-ubuntu-x64.latest.deb
wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/beta/Installers/Latest/dotnet-sdk-ubuntu-x64.latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i dotnet-host-ubuntu-x64.latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i dotnet-sharedframework-ubuntu-x64.latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i dotnet-sdk-ubuntu-x64.latest.deb
```

And then ran the same command, same error.

So then I followed the steps at
http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/coreclr/getting-started-linux.html#create-a-new-project

The project.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "ConsoleApp",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ran `dotnet restore` and the same error:

```
Errors in /home/joel/Projects/EFTest/project.json
    Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 supports:
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile78)
    Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.1 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.1 supports:
      - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
    Package System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.36 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.36 supports: portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
    One or more packages are incompatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

NuGet Config files used:
    /home/joel/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
    https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

So then I doctored the project to have the latest versions:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Commands": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "ConsoleApp",
        "ef": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Commands"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a restore gave me this:

```
Errors in /home/joel/Projects/EFTest/project.json
    Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 supports:
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile78)
    Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 supports:
      - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
    One or more packages are incompatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
```

Please help, I really want to get a proof of concept going in Linux but this seems unlikely.

Thanks

Comment: Remove dnxCore from project.json - and maybe wait for the RC2 with releated guidance here: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what to replace dnxcore with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a proof of concept project with .net core beta-7/sqLite, and it was working on linux. I'm in the middle of migrating it to RC2.

It is a known issue, please find the workaround here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases/tag/1.0.0-rc2-final#issue132